# How to invoke a powershell command stored in string with credential?

Tags: powershell

I would like to build a command from different string parts...

```
function Set-ADUserProperty ( $userSam, $propertyName, $propertyValue, $cred )
{
   $command = "Set-ADUser -Identity '$userSam' -$propertyName '$propertyValue'"
   Invoke-Expression $command
}
```

I would like to use it like this...

```
$myCred = Get-Credential myAdminUser
Set-ADUserProperty -userSam 'joedoe' -propertyName 'MobilePhone' -propertyValue '1234567' -cred $myCred
Set-ADUserProperty -userSam 'joedoe' -propertyName 'Title' -propertyValue 'SD operator' -cred $myCred
```

It worx fine without credential...
Unfortunately I don't know how to run it with credential :-(

Comment: Try: `$command = "Set-ADUser -Identity '$userSam' -$propertyName '$propertyValue'" -Credential $cred`

Comment: I've tried... the string cannot contain the (credential)object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worx!

insted of...

```
Invoke-Expression $command
```

should use...

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param ($cred); $cmd="Set-ADUser -Identity 'joedoe' -MobilePhone '1234567' -Credential `$cred"; Invoke-Expression $cmd} -ArgumentList $cred
```